# Unknown class swift

Tags: swift3, xcode8

I have for months tried to find what causes the following in Xcode. I have deleted the temporary files, searched through the MainStoryboard file - no success.. I dont know how to fix it.. Source code of project is on GitHub (https://github.com/rsyncOSX/Version3.x).

One problem solved - the second issue is still there. Have searched through Main.storyboard file, cannot spot the problem. The ViewController IDed by 3xI-3C-guU is valid. I am also finding reference to fs3-Ij-mBm searching in Main.storyboard.

> 2016-12-19 09:06:43.068961 RsyncOSX[10461:604908] Unknown class
>   _TtC8RsyncOSX21TabViewControllerMain in Interface Builder file at path /Volumes/Home/thomas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RsyncOSX-budzkonsqjvzovfxbfnmopllerwh/Build/Products/Debug/RsyncOSX.app/Contents/Resources/Base.lproj/Main.storyboardc/NSWindowController-abu-zT-Ht4.nib.
>
> 2016-12-19 09:06:43.270247 RsyncOSX[10461:604908] Unknown class View
>   in Interface Builder file at path
>   /Volumes/Home/thomas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RsyncOSX-budzkonsqjvzovfxbfnmopllerwh/Build/Products/Debug/RsyncOSX.app/Contents/Resources/Base.lproj/Main.storyboardc/3xI-3C-guU-view-fs3-Ij-mBm.nib.

Comment: Isn't it `ViewControllertabMain` according to the source code?

Comment: Hmm, how can I check that? It should be? Dont understand why it should not?

Comment: Looks like the custom class in Interface Builder has got the wrong name.

Comment: Is it possible to find where the wrong name is set and delete it? I have (some time ago) tried search and edit the Main.storyboard file but messed it up....

Comment: Search it: Press ⇧⌘F and type or copy&paste `TabViewControllerMain`

Comment: Found it, thanks. It solved one of the issues.. The tabViewController referred to a non existing source code..

Comment: The second issue is similar: *Unknown class **View** in Interface Builder*. Search for `View`.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can occur when you change a classname of a UIViewController even though a storyboard does still have the old classname. You can fix this by finding out which storyboard it is that is causing this problem (try the search function in Xcode, it will tell you that you can find `classname` in file `example.storyboard`) and update the name accordingly.